# For loop did not run

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I got code where i implement class with stucture. Almost all operators are overloaded and they are fine. But in method `insert()` is strange bahavior: its not running `for` loop even the simplest one. if its make a diffrents `for-each` loop on `ArrayList` works well.

```
class ArrayList
{
public:
   int siz;
   T *ptr;
   int cap;

   struct Iterator
   {
       T *sptr;
       bool operator<=(const Iterator &lhs);

       Iterator &operator++();

       Iterator &operator--();
       T &operator*();
   };
   Iterator &operator++();
   Iterator &operator--();
};

typename ArrayList<T>::Iterator ArrayList<T>::insert(Iterator it, T &&x)
{
   for (int a = 0; a++; a <= 5)
   {
       cout << "ins" << endl;
   }
   cout << "ah";
}


template <class T>
typename ArrayList<T>::Iterator &ArrayList<T>::Iterator::operator++()
{
   Iterator::sptr++;
   return *this;
}
```

When i use '''insert()''' method its prints only "ah". -Wall dont see any problems.

Im really really confused

Comment: `for (int a = 0; a <= 5; a++)` Dude!

Comment: Just to nitpick a little: The shown code is not a [mcve]. It contains more code than is needed to showcase your problem. At the same time it also lacks code to make it build (where's the `insert` function *declaration*).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have messed up the order of the statements. #2 is the condition so it should look like this:

```
(int a = 0; a <= 5; a++)
```

and not like this

```
(int a = 0; a++; a <= 5)
```